# Roles and permissions issues in laravel project

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on a laravel project. I have a side menu that is persistent across all pages. However the menu items to be shown is dependent on the role assigned to the user. I achieved that by doing this:

```
<?php
        /**$links = Session::get('links'); **/
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
        $id_hr_employee= Auth::user()->id_hr_employee;
        $links = DB::select("select a.link as links from sys_menu_links as a a.id_hr_employee = $id_hr_employee)
            ");
        ?>
        @if(isset($links))
            @foreach($links as $link)
                <li><hr class="light-grey-hr mb-10"/></li>
                @include("$link->links")
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

This works quite alright. However, if someone enters a route to a menu (that he is not assigned to) on the address bar, he sees that page. 
Please how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would highly recommend you using laratrust: https://laratrust.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/.
And to secure your sides: 1.option work with middelware to Block your admin views 2. Option Check for permission in the Controller files.
As a guidance you could look up this tutorial: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-user-acl-roles-and-permissions-with-middleware-using-entrust-from-scratch-tutorialexample.html

greetings